# What is the minimal subset of file methods I need to implement to get the full python file interface?

Tags: python

Python has the marvelous [`collections`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) module that has tools to allow you to implement a full `dict` (for example) from a minimal set of methods. Is there a similar thing for the `file` interface in Python? If not, what would you recommend as a minimal set of methods to implement for a `file`-like object for duck-typing purposes?

And how do you deal with things that would like to use your file like object in a `with` statement, like you can with a regular file, or who want to iterate over it (like you can with a regular file) or who want to be able to call `readline` or `readlines` and have it do something intelligent and useful (like you can with a regular file)? Do you have to implement them all yourself? Or are there better options?

I know I can implement each and every single one of these myself, by hand. But the `collections` interface allows me to implement a `dict` by implementing just `__len__`, `__iter__`, `__setitem__`, and `__getitem__`. I get `pop`, `popitem`, `clear`, `update`, `setdefault`, `__contains__`, `keys`, `items`, `values`, `get`, `__eq__`, and `__ne__` all for free. There is a minimal interface for `__dict__` defined, and if I implement it, I get the full `dict` interface, all of the extra methods being implemented in terms of the minimal interface.

Similarly, I would like to know what the minimal interface for file is that I have to implement in order to get the full interface. Is there a way to get `__enter__`, `__exit__`, `readline`, `readlines`, `__iter__` and `next` if I just implement `read`, `write` and `close`, or do I have to implement everything myself by hand each and every time I want the full `file` interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The with statement requires a context  manager:

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager

The file type is fully defined:

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects

Seems pretty simple.

The documentation lists the methods and attributes of a file and a context manager.  Implement those.

What more information do you need?

http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html?highlight=context%20manager

If you want all the methods to work, you have to implement all the methods. Unlike the collections, there is no abstract base class for files.

Comment: I want to know, is there any way to avoid having to implement all that stuff myself? There already is a context manager for file-like objects, there is already a line buffer for file-like objects, there's already an iterator for file-like objects. Is there any way I can use those instead of having to implement them myself? I would like to be able to get away with only implementing a `read` and `write` method myself.

Comment: @Omnifarious.  You only implement what your application actually needs.  If your application only needs read and write, then that's all you implement.  A "line buffer" doesn't make sense.  An iterator is trivial (it's a function with `yield`.)  The context manager, similarly, can be used from the `contextlib` package.  It may not be a lot of code.  Since your question is vague, the answer must necessarily be vague.  If you provided some examples of how you want to use your new file-like object, we could provide more concrete advice.

Comment: @Omnifarious. If you want all the methods to work, you have to implement all the methods.  Unlike the collections, there is no abstract base class for files.

Comment: @S.Lott: That's the answer I was looking for. I'm sad this is the case, and I hope it's fixed in a future version of Python. Thanks.

Comment: @Omnifarious. "I hope it's fixed"?  Hope what's fixed?  The various methods don't depend much on each other.

Comment: @S.Lott: Really? You mean Linux implements buffered read and write, readline and iteration over a file in the kernel? All of these are very useful, and they are implemented in terms of a basic read, write, seek and close interface. I should be able to provide something that has a similarly simple and get all the other nice file things for free. It is a deficiency of Python that this is not the case.

Comment: @Omnifarious I agree that it would be nice if you could implement `read`, `write` and `close` and have things like `readline` and `__iter__` taken care of for you, but there aren't that many that could be automatically derived from others. For example, you cite `__enter__` and `__exit__` -- those highly depend on what the object really is. `next` is not a method of file-like objects, it is a method of iterator objects returned by `__iter__`. So it wouldn't help that much.

Comment: @Omnifarious: "Linux implements buffered read and write, readline and iteration over a file in the kernel?"  What does that have to do with anything?  We're not talking about low-level I/O.  We're talking about the Python functions and the various argument signatures to those functions.  Read them carefully, the *intent* behind the size of a read, the limit on  a readlines and the absence of arguments on the iterator make them rather different in their implementation.

Comment: @S.Lott: Is there any good reason that I should not be able to provide any object that supports the Unix `read`, `write` and possibly `lseek` calls and get back an object with the full Python file semantics, including minimizing calls to my object using buffering? After all, it's what Python is doing already.

Comment: @Omnifarious: AFAIK, the Python `file` class doesn't depend on some secret, internal File class that simply wraps OS-level methods.  The Python file class is based on the C STDIO library, and it's abstractions.  You do have the source for the `file` class on your computer.

Comment: @S.Lott: How is that relevant to my question? I want a way to do this in Python without having to re-write a whole bunch of stuff. Python is already doing what I want to do, why can't I give it some other object than a file descriptor and have it work?

Comment: @Omnifarious: "why can't I give it some other object than a file descriptor and have it work?"  Because it doesn't work that way.  I'm well aware that you don't want to "re-write a whole bunch of stuff".  It's in the question and the comments over and over again.  If you read the source for `file`, you'll learn how they do it  and how to minimize the amount of stuff you need to write.  I encourage you to actually look at the actual source for the file class.

Comment: @S.Lott - I may do that. I may also try to write something that works the way I think it should. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would look at io.IOBase[1] and io.RawIOBase for >2.6 compatibility. This will keep you moving forward with 3.x (io implements the 3.x file interface).

[1] http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#i-o-base-classes

Comment: These look like a start at what I'm after, but the documentation for them is a bit confusing. Anyway, thank you for pointing me at them.

Comment: you're welcome, after reading your other comment TextIO might be the one you really want.

Comment: The thing I'm unclear on, can you give TextIO something the implements RawIOBase and get a TextIO interface to it?

Comment: That I don't know, the only real advice in this case is to experiment with it.

Answer (score 2):

You kind of answered it yourself. While there is no set of "special" methods you need to implement the file interface, you can do it just by providing a couple of methods normally associated with files. Duck typing takes care of the rest.

You only really need a `read` and/or a `write` method (depending on whether you want it to be readable and/or writable) which behave the same as a normal file object. You can have a look at the [Python file object](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) reference to see all of the methods of a file object. Basically, the more you implement, the more situations your class will work in place of a file. (For example, if you implement `seek`, then it will work in any function that performs seeking on a file.) Note that there is a continuum here, there is no absolute "it supports the file protocol or it doesn't." In fact, there is no way to work 100% in all the places that support file-like objects, because some code will access low-level details of the real `file` type, and yours won't work there.

In summary, any class that implements `read` and `write` will work in most situations that require a "file-like object".

(Note that the special method names like `__getitem__` for dicts are really not special, except they are used by special syntax like `[key]` -- thats why dict has special method names and file does not.)

Comment: I understand about `read` and `write`. But some things depend on `__iter__` and `readline` and other features of file. How do I deal with things that want those without having to re-implement them? Or, even better, Python's special newline handling for my own file-like objects?

Comment: This answer really does not work for me, since it implies that I will have to re-implement a whole host of `file` functionality (buffering, newline handling, readlines, writelines, `__enter__` and `__exit__` for use with `with`, etc..) for each and every file-like object I want to implement. Is there any way at all to get around this?

Comment: @Omnifarious: The answer is the answer.  "This answer really does not work for me, since it implies that I will have to re-implement a whole host of file functionality"  Is irrelevant.  Too bad that you  have to implement everything.  That doesn't change the answer, does it?