# Lazyily filtering a file before reading

Tags: python, file

Suppose I have a BIG file with some lines I wish to ignore, and a function (`file_function`) which takes a file object. Can I return a new file object whose lines satisfy some condition **without reading the entire file first**, this **laziness** is the important part.

*Note: I could just save a temporary file with these lines ignored, but this is not ideal.*

For example, suppose I had a csv file (with a bad line):

```
1,2
ooops
3,4
```

A first attempt was to create new file object (with same methods as file) and overwrite `readline`:

```
class FileWithoutCondition(file):
    def __init__(self, f, condition):
        self.f = f
        self.condition = condition
    def readline(self):
        while True:
            x = self.f.readline()
            if self.condition(x):
                return x
```

*This works if `file_name` only uses `readline`... but not if it requires some other functionality.*

```
with ('file_name', 'r') as f:
    f1 = FileWithoutOoops(f, lambda x: x != 'ooops\n')
    result = file_function(f1)
```

*A solution using StringIO may work, but I can't seem to get it to.*

Ideally we should assume that `file_function` is a blackbox function, specifically I can't just tweak it to accept a generator (but maybe I can tweak a generator to be file-like?).
**Is there a standard way to do this kind of lazy (skim-)reading of a generic file?**

*Note: the motivating example to this question is [this pandas question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088190/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-load-a-filtered-tda-file-using-pandas), where just having a `readline` is not enough to get `pd.read_csv` working...*

Comment: I think you need to clarify for us exactly what the requirements on the "file" object are.  If it needs more than just the ability to generate lines, we need to know what else.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I think you could be correct, I was hoping there could be some generic way to do this (that would work with any "file". Perhaps this was naive...

Comment: Perhaps.  :)  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335017/what-is-the-minimal-subset-of-file-methods-i-need-to-implement-to-get-the-full-p if you haven't already.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thanks for that, I hadn't seen it!

Comment: Has another answer turned up since 2013, that works with `pd.read_csv` and `json.load` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a map-reduce approach with existing Python facilities. In this example I'm using a regular expression for matching lines that start with the string `GET /index`, but you can use whatever condition fits your bill:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

pattern = re.compile(r'GET /index\(.*\).html')

# define FILE appropriately.
# map
# the condition here serves to filter lines that can not match.
matches = (pattern.search(line) for line in file(FILE, "rb") if 'GET' in line)
mapp    = (match.group(1) for match in matches if match)

# now reduce, lazy:
count = defaultdict(int)
for request in mapp:
    count[request] += 1
```

This scans a >6GB file in a few seconds on my laptop. You can further split a file in chunks and feed them to threads or processes. Use of `mmap` I do not recommend unless you have the memory to map the entire file (it doesn't support windowing).

Comment: Isn't this a generator rather than being file-like? Similar to the answer (deleted) below?

Comment: Is that a problem? You can wrap the `mapp = ...` generator in your file-like class' `readline` and yield from it, but I would not do that, because there's no abstract class for a file, so you have to implement all methods.

Comment: perhaps the no abstract class for a file is the issue, I was hoping I could just pretend it was a file. The [motivating example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088190/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-load-a-filtered-tda-file-using-pandas) has `file_function=pd.read_csv` (which needs more than readline). :(